# Count number of elements in a specific range in an array

Tags: matlab, octave

I am pretty new to matlab and I want to find out how to count the elements af an array that are in a specific range. For example lets say I have an array A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] and I want to find out how many elemnts are between 1 and 3 ( [1,3] ), how many are between [4,6] and how many are between [7,9]. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: `sum(A >= 1 &A<=3)` ?

Comment: So you want to make a [histogram](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html)?